# Do-until loop in SQL to pull date of a specified data entry per id

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way to loop through my data to obtain the date of a specified data entry?

Example:
The first entry of 'Y' in column type for id 1 was made on 2022-01-01.

```
id type date
1  Y    2022-01-01
1  Y    2022-01-09
1  X    2022-01-12
2  Y    2022-01-08
2  X    2022-01-09
2  X    2022-01-12
```

AS [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kPTJq-I8)

I want to keep the date of the first entry of 'Y' and keep it for the following entries

```
id type date        Start
1  Y    2022-01-01  2022-01-01
1  Y    2022-01-09  2022-01-01
1  X    2022-01-12  2022-01-01
2  Y    2022-01-08  2022-01-08
2  X    2022-01-09  2022-01-08
2  X    2022-01-12  2022-01-08
```

Thanks in advance

PP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function to get the minimum 'Y' date for each id:

```
select tab.*, min(case when type = 'Y' then date end) over (partition by id)
from tab
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/l_FUKvq_

Comment: Very good, but this solution does not contain 'Y'. What about this circumstance?  https://dbfiddle.uk/OAr_ydTy

Comment: Missed that part, stay tuned for an update. (You could improve the sample data too...)